# Gitlab-CI: execute a job on the master branch or if a tag has been created on the master branch?

Tags: gitlab-ci

How can I only execute a job on the master branch or if a tag has been created on the master branch?

I would like the trigger_job to be executed last in every situation on the master branch, if all jobs were previously successful.

```
publish_dev:
  # should only run on master branch
  only:
    - master

publish_prd:
  # should only run if a tag has been created on the master branch
  only:
   - tags:
  except: 
   - branches

triger_job:
  # should always run on the master branch
  only:
   - master
  needs:
   - job: publish_dev
   - job: publish_prd
```

At the moment I get the following error message from the CI-Job, when there has been no tag created on the master branch.

```
'trigger_job' job needs 'publish_prd' job but it was not added to the pipeline
```

If I have no "needs" section in the trigger_job, the job starts before finishing the publish_dev or publish_prd job.

Answer (score 0):

```html
publish_prd:
  # should only run if a tag has been created on the master branch
  only:
   - tags:
  except: 
   - branches

triger_job:
  # should always run on the master branch
  only:
   - master
  needs:
   - job: publish_dev
   - job: publish_prd
```

From what we see is that trigger_job needs job publish_prd and _dev, and run only on master, but publish_prd run only on tags, so trigger job cannot find it when its on master. So to avoid conflict, just add another tigger job for tags only.